Custom tabularray environment with font changes
I'm trying to learn tabularray and wanted to setup some custom environments. I really like the idea of being able to move some of the layout markup outside of the actual tabular code, but there are some combinations I can't get to work.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\NewTblrEnviron{my-tabular}
\SetTblrInner[my-tabular]{
    rows={font=\sffamily},
    row{1} = {bg=black!10,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
}

\NewColumnType{Z}{X[font=\ttfamily]}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={ZX},
            rows={font=\sffamily},
            row{1}={bg=black!10,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
        }
        Header left & Header right \\
        item 1 left & item 1 right \\
        item 2 left & item 2 right
    \end{tblr}

    \begin{my-tabular}{
        colspec={ZX},
        % row{1}={bg=black!10,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    }
    Header left & Header right \\
    item 1 left & item 1 right \\
    item 2 left & item 2 right
\end{my-tabular}

\end{document}

The first table is what I want, but if I try to move the rows and row{1} definitions into a custom environment, the font changing commands from the colspec take priority over the one in row{1}. (Note, repeating the row{1} setting in \begin{my-tabular} works, but it feels very clumsy.)
I'm probably missing something fairly obvious, but I can't figure out a way to have the definitions from \SetTblrInner to override the colspec font changes. Any ideas how to do this in user-friendly way, leaving the code for actual table as clean as possible?

Default inner options set through \SetTblrInner are executed before in-document per-environment inner options, which caused the order-dependent issue OP experienced.
Here's an attempt which adds a similar \SetTblrLateInner command. With it the execution order becomes
- default inner options      (\SetTblrInner[tblr]{...})
- in-document inner options  (\begin{tblr}{...})
- default late inner options (\SetTblrLateInner[tblr]{...})

Adding support for meta option (an option as a shortcut of a list of other options) would be another solution, and it's more flexible.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:Nc \xapptocmd { NewTblrEnviron ~ code }
  {
    \tl_new:c { l__tblr_default_ #1 _inner_late_tl }
  }
  { } { \PatchFailed }

\xapptocmd \__tblr_parse_table_spec:n
  {
    % built-in tblr envs don't have _inner_late_tl
    \cs_if_exist:cT { l__tblr_default_ \l__tblr_env_name_tl _inner_late_tl }
      {
        \keys_set:nv { tblr }
          { l__tblr_default_ \l__tblr_env_name_tl _inner_late_tl }
      }
  }
  { } { \PatchFailed }

\NewDocumentCommand \SetTblrLateInner { O{tblr} m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
      { \tl_put_right:cn { l__tblr_default_ ##1 _inner_late_tl } { , #2 } }
    \ignorespaces
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewTblrEnviron{my-tabular}
% use \SetTblrLateInner
\SetTblrLateInner[my-tabular]{
    rows={font=\sffamily},
    row{1} = {bg=black!10,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
}

\NewColumnType{Z}{X[font=\ttfamily]}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={ZX},
            rows={font=\sffamily},
            row{1}={bg=black!10,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
        }
        Header left & Header right \\
        item 1 left & item 1 right \\
        item 2 left & item 2 right
    \end{tblr}

    \begin{my-tabular}{
            colspec={ZX},
        }
        Header left & Header right \\
        item 1 left & item 1 right \\
        item 2 left & item 2 right
    \end{my-tabular}

\end{document}



Thank you! That seems to be working well, even in my more complicated real application
